# Troubleshooting Flash Events

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I wanted to ask any Flash gurus here if they have any best practices for troubleshooting Flash (custom) Events.  I'm currently dealing with a couple of events that are supposedly being dispatched but never caught by the corresponding listeners.

Here is the list of things I've already checked for:

- Event names are defined as a String const in the custom event and the event name is used in the listener.
- Checked for Event bubbling (as explained [here](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget)).

If anyone has any suggestion, It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code, we would need to see how the event is dispatched and how the listener is implemented. A common reason for errors is the event being dispatched before the listener can catch it but there are of course many other possible reasons... difficult to answer without seeing some form of implementation

Comment: I already solved it.  The problem was that the listener was not one of the parents in the DisplayList hierarchy.  I moved the listener to the closest common ancestor and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most frequent mistakes are:
1. Event listener added **after** event being already dispatched.
2. Non-overriden clone() and toString() methods for custom event.
3. Simply listening wrong objects/wrong events.

Comment: Add to that list, not knowing how events propagate. :P